# ¿Cómo crear base de datos POSTGRESQL online o intranet?

Tags: sql, postgresql, servidor

tengo un software java escritorio que usa base de datos postgres y todo me anda bien pero solo lo puedo usar en localhost, quisiera que mi aplicacion se pudiera conectar desde otro equipo ya sea por internet o intranet.

Yo uso estas variables para mi conexion

```
public static String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_monkeys_nuevo";
public static String usuario = "postgres";
public static String contrasenia = "monkey";

public static Connection getConexion() {

    try {
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_monkeys_nuevo";
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    Connection cn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, contrasenia);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(e));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de conexxion a la base de datos:\n " + e);
    }
    return cn;
}
```

se me ocurre que se debe poder cambiar mi localhost por una ip o servidor.

si fuera en intranet lo haría así:

```
public static String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.7.100:5432/db_monkeys_nuevo";
```

y si fuera online sería así:

```
public static String url = "jdbc:postgresql://www.miservidorpostgresonline.com/db_monkeys_nuevo";
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

No importa si para la forma online tengo que pagar un dominio y hosting (que es lo obvio) pero si quiero que me pueda conectar como en el ejemplo

Comment: Es exactamente como lo comentas, solo debes cambiar 'localhost' por la ip de tu servidor o por un nombre de dominio.

Comment: @E.Betanzos, si eso creo, pero ¿como creo ese servidor local o que proveedor de servicios puedo usar para la base de datos online

Comment: Si quieres la base de datos local solo tienes que instalarte el Postgres y listo. Ahora, si la quieres en internet puedes usar cualquier servicio en la nube o contratar algún hosting.

Comment: como localhost ya la tengo funcionando hace tiempo, me interesan los servicios en la nuve